# How to handle large requests from clients while changing of selection box in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, response

**I have huge list of colleges and schools at the server side for each district in a state.**

In a registration page for the user , I ask him the district and when he selects one , I am sending the request to nodejs with the district name as the request body. The server reads the district and sends the colleges list to the client where I put the list in the selection box. ( I am sending ajax requests to nodejs)

The issue is that if I click the district selection box too quickly or use the arrow keys , then it gets stuck becoz of all those internal multiple requests ?

**What are the ways of improving this method at server and client and how to handle such quick selection changes of the selection box efficiently?**

```
 var timer = 0 ;
        $('#select_district').on('change', function district_selection_changed() {

            clearTimeout(timer) ;
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/getcolleges",
                    data: {
                        state: $("#select_state").val(),
                        district: $("#select_district").val()
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#select_college").html("");
                        collegenameelement = document.getElementById("collegenameslist") ;
                        response.forEach((ele) => collegenameelement.innerHTML =  collegenameelement.innerHTML+
                            `<option>${ele}</option>`)
                    }
                })

            } , 500) ;
```

Comment: [`debounce`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounce) from [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) or similar techniques from other libraries. Or write something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best that you delay execution of the request for a short time after the last time it is called. This behavior is usually referred to as `debounce` function, it is supported by many utility libraries, like Underscore, Lodash etc...

If you don't want to install an entire library for just one function, you can check their code and implement you own.

You can also block user from select a new district if a request is still being process, and show them the a loading icon if needed.

Comment: "You can also block user from select a new district if a request is still being process, and show them the a loading icon if needed." How to do this blocking .please tell me

Comment: You can disable the input field when making the request, and only re-enable it when the response comes back

Comment: I don't know why but when using either debounce and Throttling , the UI just hangs when I am selecting the states frequently even by mouse . Why is this happeneing ?  As of disabling how do i disable it ?